# Pyspark withColumn Not Returning Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe 'df' that i parse.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, trim, lit 

    df2 = df.withColumn("value", regexp_extract("_c0", "(? 
    <=value':\s)\d+", 0))\
    .withColumn("time", regexp_extract("_c1", "(? 
    <=time':\su')\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(?=('}))", 0))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

It returns

```
    +-------------+----------------------+-----+--------+
    |_c0          |_c1                   |value|time    |
    +-------------+----------------------+-----+--------+
    |{u'value': 76| u'time': u'00:36:32'}|76   |00:36:32|
    |{u'value': 77| u'time': u'00:36:42'}|77   |00:36:42|
    |{u'value': 76| u'time': u'00:36:47'}|76   |00:36:47|
    |{u'value': 77| u'time': u'00:36:57'}|77   |00:36:57|
    |{u'value': 78| u'time': u'00:37:02'}|78   |00:37:02|
    |{u'value': 77| u'time': u'00:37:07'}|77   |00:37:07|
```

When i try to do more manipulations to df2, I get

```
    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Why is df2 no longer a dataframe that i can manipulate?

Instead of .show() I try .toDF() and get

```
    u"requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't 
    match.\nOld column names (4): _c0, _c1, value, time\nNew 
    column names (0):
```

And .collect() returns  rows.
I just want another dataframe returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing **.show()** action while creating **df2** dataframe, That's the reason why `df2` is not a dataframe anymore.

**Create df2 dataframe without `.show()` action:**

```
>>> df2 = df.withColumn("value", regexp_extract("_c0", "(? 
    <=value':\s)\d+", 0))\
    .withColumn("time", regexp_extract("_c1", "(? 
    <=time':\su')\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(?=('}))", 0))
```

Now do `.show()` on df2 dataframe:

```
>>> df2.show()
```